# batch file FOR loop weird output with "bcdedit"

Tags: batch-file, bcdedit

I am trying to understand the FOR loop in batch files. This code:

```
FOR /F %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO @echo %%V
pause
exit
```

Gives this output:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>FOR /F %V IN ('bcdedit') DO @echo %V
The
Access

C:\Users\me\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

bcdedit is a program to configure the boot manager.
running bcdedit at the console gives:

```
Windows Boot Manager                                                            
--------------------                                                            
identifier              {bootmgr}                                               
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1                       
description             Windows Boot Manager                                    
locale                  en-US                                                   
inherit                 {globalsettings}                                        
integrityservices       Enable                                                  
default                 {current}                                               
resumeobject            {5af9a946-5290-11e3-bd93-d2aed7e9b7a5}                  
displayorder            {current}                                               
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}                                               
timeout                 30                                                      

Windows Boot Loader                                                             
-------------------                                                             
identifier              {current}                                               
device                  partition=C:                                            
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe                           
description             Windows 8.1                                             
locale                  en-US                                                   
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}                                    
recoverysequence        {5af9a948-5290-11e3-bd93-d2aed7e9b7a5}                  
integrityservices       Enable                                                  
recoveryenabled         Yes                                                     
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075                                              
osdevice                partition=C:                                            
systemroot              \Windows                                                
resumeobject            {5af9a946-5290-11e3-bd93-d2aed7e9b7a5}                  
nx                      OptIn                                                   
bootmenupolicy          Standard                                                
useplatformclock        Yes
```

Where do the words "The" and "Access" come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran bcdedit without Admin privileges, which produces the following output:

```
The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
Access is denied.
```

Your output comes from the first word on each line. Make sure you are running in an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try

```
FOR /F "delims=" %V IN ('bcdedit') DO @echo %V
```

to see the entire line.

I'd suggest that `Access` may be the first token from a response `Access Denied`

Comment: thank you. but I tried your code and the console window blinked out of existence so fast even though I had a PAUSE in the second line of the bat script. I had to use %%V. Why? Another question for the ages...